# Store into a database table as row the query result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, object

query result

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ingredientID] => 2
        [code] => Bf
        [description] => 1st Class Flour
        [volume] => 8268
        [price] => 750
        [amount_gram] => 0.02980
        [status] => Inactive
        [uom_id] => 1
        [flour] => Yes
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ingredientID] => 3
        [code] => Sf
        [description] => 3rd Class Flour
        [volume] => 18490
        [price] => 635
        [amount_gram] => 0.02540
        [status] => Inactive
        [uom_id] => 5
        [flour] => Yes
    )
..........
```

I want to store this results into another table as row inventory.
the table will look like this:

```
ID        inventory
1         (the result)
2         (another result)
```

And after I will query it back again so that I can display the result.

here's what I have done lately.

store:

```
//getting the result
$inv = $this->db->get_from('table','id'=>'1')->row();
<input type="hidden" name="inventory" value="<?php print_r($inv)?>">
//storing in the new table
$this->db->insert('table2',array('inventory'=>$this->input->post('inventory')));
```

getting:

```
$inventory = $this->db->get_where('table2',array('ID'=>'1'))->row_array();
//result
array
(
      [ID] => 1
      [inventory] =>
      array
      (
            [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                 [ingredientID] => 2
                 ...... and so on
```

I want to display everything in the array['inventory'] which is an array of objects.

I've done this
    foreach($arr['inventory'] as $invent):
            echo $invent['ingredientID'];

but there's an error in the foreach part.
error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

What should i do?
        endforeach;

Comment: Where's `$arr` defined? I can't see it anywhere but `foreach`.

Comment: assuming $arr is the array that contains the array of objects

Comment: The only thing I can tell you is that `$arr['inventory']` is not an array. try `var_dump` it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming:

```
$results = $this->db->get_where('table2',array('ID'=>'1'))->row_array();
```

you should use this to print it

```
foreach($results['inventory'] as $inventory)
{
    print_r($inventory->ingredientID);
}
```